# Second recv() hangs

Tags: c, unix

My client sends two c-strings to the server, only one is received the second recv() just hangs and I have to CTRL-C out of my program.

How can I get both messages to receive?
Here is the area I am having trouble with.

```
 //SERVER CODE
 // Retrieve plaintext from the client while connected.
 while ((n = recv(client_socket, buffer_a, sizeof(buffer_a), 0)) > 0)   {

   buffer_a[n] = '\0';

   // Retrieve the key from the client.
   // PROBLEM HERE - THIS WILL DO NOTHING AND PROGRAM HANGS
   if (recv(client_socket, buffer_b, sizeof(buffer_b)-1, 0) == -1) {
      perror("recv key error");
   }

}


//CLIENT CODE
while ((n = read(fileno(plain_text), buffer_a, sizeof(buffer_a)-1))
0)    
/*Read contents of file*/
{
   // Format the buffer as a c-string.
   buffer_a[n] = '\0';

   // Get the key.
   if (read(fileno(key), buffer_b, sizeof(n)-1) == -1) {
      perror("read key file error");
      exit(1);
   }
   buffer_b[n] = '\0';

   // Send plaintext to the server.
   if (send(client_fd, buffer_a, n, 0) == -1) {
      perror("send plaintext error");
      exit(1);
   }

   // Send key to the server.
   if (send(client_fd, buffer_b, n, 0) == -1)
   {
      perror("send key error");
      exit(1);
   }
}
```

Comment: `recv` will try to read as much data as is available. So it is likely that your first `recv` call has read **all** the data from both of the client's `send` calls. You need to check how much data was read and parse the results into the relevant buffers. This can mean that the data is split across multiple receives.

Comment: That was it, I removed the second recv() and parsed the buffer. Thank you.